# Dynamic Paint is not working

Tags: dynamic-paint

I'm trying to make an animation showing a nail mark on the surface. But the trace is not displayed even in render mode. What could I have done wrong? Subdivide is applied to the surface.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: since you seem to be a beginner - pls provide blend file so we can check it out. thx.

Comment: Is the surface subdivided with a high resolution? In the _Canvas_ you have set the _Format_ to _Vertex_ and _Surface Type_ to _Displace_. To displace the vertices, there have to be vertices - if your canvas is just a single large face with only four vertices at the corners, there is no geometry to displace.

Answer (score 0):

Although your setup is not yet perfectly clear and there are various possibilities which could be the problem, here is one that might occur when you are a beginner and are not so familiar with how these things work (at least I had this problem when I first used *Dynamic Paint*):

In order for the canvas to be displaced properly with the brush, there needs to be enough geometry to be displaced. If your canvas is for example a simple default plane or a flattened cube, the surface you are trying to displace is just one large single face with only 4 vertices in the corners. Trying to use *Dynamic Paint* looks like this, above the canvas mesh in *Edit Mode* and below the resulting (not existing) displacement:

[image: canvas low resolution]

Although the sphere is correctly set up as brush, there is no displacement at all. However, when you subdivide the canvas to have a high resolution surface, the resulting displacement looks much better:

[image: canvas high resolution]